# can not use list in pmap function in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have 2 vectors(`respose` and `pca`) and 1 list(`test`) and I want use them with `expand.grid`:

```
final = rbind(
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[1]],pre2=pca[1],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[2]],pre2=pca[2],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[3]],pre2=pca[3],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[4]],pre2=pca[4],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[5]],pre2=pca[5],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[6]],pre2=pca[6],stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
  expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[7]],pre2=pca[7],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)
```

There is too much repeatable code and I rewrite the code use `map_dfr`:

```
final2 <- map_dfr(1:7, 
                  ~ expand.grid(response = response,pre1=test[[.]],pre2=pca[.],stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Then I also want to use `pmap_dfr` to do this but get an error:

```
agrg.list = list(response = response, pre1 = test, pre2 = pca)

final3 <- pmap_dfr(agrg.list, 
                   ~expand.grid(response = response, pre1 = unlist(pre1), pre2= pre2, stringsAsFactors = F))
```

> Error: Element 1 of `.l` must have length 1 or 7, not 5

I want to know if the code can only rewrite by `map_dfr` not `pamp_dfr`.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

And this is my 2 vectors and 1 list :

```
test <- list(c("PM2_5_s_lag_1", "PM2_5_m_lag_1", "PM2_5_s_lag_2", "PM2_5_m_lag_2", 
               "PM2_5_s_lag_3", "PM2_5_m_lag_3"), c("pca_PMC", "PMC_s_lag_1", 
                                                    "PMC_m_lag_1", "PMC_s_lag_2", "PMC_m_lag_2", "PMC_s_lag_3", "PMC_m_lag_3"
               ), c("pca_PM10", "PM10_s_lag_1", "PM10_m_lag_1", "PM10_s_lag_2", 
                    "PM10_m_lag_2", "PM10_s_lag_3", "PM10_m_lag_3"), c("NO2_s_lag_1", 
                                                                       "NO2_m_lag_1", "NO2_s_lag_2", "NO2_m_lag_2", "NO2_s_lag_3", "NO2_m_lag_3"
                    ), c("SO2_s_lag_1", "SO2_m_lag_1", "SO2_s_lag_2", "SO2_m_lag_2", 
                         "SO2_s_lag_3", "SO2_m_lag_3"), c("CO_s_lag_1", "CO_m_lag_1", 
                                                          "CO_s_lag_2", "CO_m_lag_2", "CO_s_lag_3", "CO_m_lag_3"), c("O3_s_lag_1", 
                                                                                                                     "O3_m_lag_1", "O3_s_lag_2", "O3_m_lag_2", "O3_s_lag_3", "O3_m_lag_3"
                                                          ))


pca <- c("pca_pm2_5", "pca_PMC", "pca_PM10", "pca_NO2", "pca_SO2", "pca_CO", 
         "pca_O3")

response <- c("X0.whole", "X0.man", "X0.woman", "X0.agelo65", "X0.ageupwith65"
)
```

Comment: `pca` and  `response` should have the same length, response[7] doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` variable is constant and does not change so you should not pass it in any of the `map` function. As there are only 2 variables which change use `map2_df`.

```
purrr::map2_df(test, pca, ~expand.grid(response, pre1 = .x, pre2 = .y))
```

Or this can also be written with `pmap_df` as :

```
purrr::pmap_df(list(test, pca), ~expand.grid(response, pre1 = ..1, pre2 = ..2))
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to pass the complete vector `respons` to each call within the `pmap_dfr`. To do that you need to make a list with 7 copies of the `response` vector. You can do this with

```
rep(list(response), 7)
```

The complete construction of the `agrg.list` would then look like this.

```
agrg.list = list(response = rep(list(response), 7), pre1 = test, pre2 = pca)
```

The rest will then work as expected.